# Kubernetes: Bind physical network interface

Tags: kubernetes, binding, vpn, network-interface

Is it possible to bind a Kubernetes pod or container to a physical network interface of the host such that all traffic arriving on the interface is sent to the pod (not just HTTP traffic on a specific port)?

Specifically, I want to start a VPN client as a pod on Kubernetes and bind it to a network interface. All traffic arriving on the interface should go via the pod through the VPN.

I found something about [Network Plugins in K8s](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/), but that seems to be something else.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly you can do it. I am exposing an amqp application just by exposing the amqp port of my application via a NodePort service. What you need to do is define a new service which is almost exactly a service that you use for internal interaction but use `LoadBalancer` or `NodePort` as the service type.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your answer correctly. But wouldn't `NodePort` (or `LoadBalancer`) not just expose a few ports publiclly? What I want is to pass all incoming traffic at a network interface (not just of a certain port). Not sure if I'm mixing things up here.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this could solve your problem https://github.com/intel/multus-cni. It allows you to have multiple network interfaces inside of a pod.